# Why are these sets not equal?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

Given 1) the power set of the natural numbers.

And 2) the set $\{T\subseteq\mathbb{N}\ |\ T$ is finite or $\mathbb{N}\setminus T $ is finite}.

---

We know that in 2) there are all finite subsets of the natural numbers. For every infinite subset $T$, there is the finite complement $\mathbb{N}\setminus T$, so now we have all infinite subsets *also* in the set 2).

But these are *all* the subsets of the natural numbers, so the power set.

---

I am asking because I got an assignment in which I have to prove that set 2) is *not* complete. But since 1) and 2) are equal and the power set is complete, 2) must be complete, too.

So, the only way 2) can be not complete is, when 2) and 1) are not equal.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: (1) is the discrete $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{N}$, (2) is the finite and co-finite $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: neptun gives, in his (or her) answer, an example of a set which is neither finite, nor co-finite, the set of even numbers, so you're missing something. What is wrong in your reasoning is that if $T \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is infinite, it doesn't follow that $\mathbb{N} \setminus T$ is finite. Using that example, if $T$ is the set of even numbers, then $\mathbb{N} \setminus T$ is the set of odd numbers, which is also infinite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, consider the even numbers. Neither them nor the complement is finite!